# Getting images to change in a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

So far I created an array with 11 images, initialized the counter, created a function, created a for loop but here is where I get lost. I looked at examples and tutorial on the internet and I can see the code is seeming simple but I'm not getting something basic here. I don't actually understand how to call the index for the images. Any suggestions. Here is the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var hammer=new Array("jackhammer0.gif",
                "jackhammer1.gif",
                "jackhammer2.gif",
                "jackhammer3.gif",
                "jackhammer4.gif",
                "jackhammer5.gif",
                "jackhammer6.gif",
                "jackhammer7.gif",
                "jackhammer8.gif",
                "jackhammer9.gif",
                "jackhammer10.gif")
 var curHammer=0;

 var numImg = 11;
 function getHammer() {

   for (i = 0; i < hammer.length; i++)
   {
     if (curHammer < hammer.length - 1) {
       curHammer = curHammer +1;
       hammer[i] = new Image();
       hammer[i].src="poses/jackhammer" +(i+1) + ".gif";

       var nextHammer = curHammer + 1;
       nextHammer=0;
       {
       }
     }
   }
 }


 setTimeout("getHammer()", 5000);

 </script>
</head>
 <body onload = "getHammer()";>
 <img id="jack" name="jack" src = "poses/jackhammer0.gif" width= "100" height ="113" alt =   "Man      and Jackhammer" /><br/>
 <button id="jack" name="jack" onclick="getHammer()">Press button</button>
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting voted down.I did everything right. What's the problem

Comment: What is this code snippet supposed to do?

Comment: I think you are using hammer[i].src in your for loop.What it mean?Actually you need to use documeny.getElementById('IMAGE_ID').

Comment: The first image loads on the page and changes to the next image in the array until all 11 images have looped. That's basically what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on what Paul, said, here's an example of what should work:

```
var hammer=["jackhammer0.gif","jackhammer1.gif","jackhammer2.gif","jackhammer3.gif",
    "jackhammer4.gif","jackhammer5.gif","jackhammer6.gif","jackhammer7.gif",
    "jackhammer8.gif","jackhammer9.gif","jackhammer10.gif"];

var curHammer=0;

function getHammer() {
    if (curHammer < hammer.length) {
        document.getElementById("jack").src= "poses/" + hammer[curHammer];
        curHammer = curHammer + 1;
    }
}

setTimeout("getHammer()", 5000);
```

The big missing element is that you need to call getElementById("jack") to get a reference to the DOM Image so that you can change it's source. If you're using jQuery or most other JS frameworks, just type $("#jack") to accomplish the same.

Comment: See, that's what I was looking for, the logic. Now it's starting to make sense. And I thought I needed a for loop.

Comment: Glad to help. Nope, no for loop is needed because the timer you setup with setTimeout behaves like a loop since it runs once ever 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the for loop at all, just increment the index value [curHammer] each time you click, and reset if it passes your max index length (in this case 11).

Pseudo-Code:

```
  currentHammer = -1
  hammers = [ "a1.jpg", "a2.jpg", "a3.jpg"]

  getHammer()
  {
       currentHammer = currentHammer + 1;
       if(currentHammer > 2)
           currentHammer = 0;
       image.src = hammers[currentHammer];
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to reset *currentHammer*, just do `image.src = hammers[++currentHammer % hammers.length]` which will only return values in the range *0* to *hammers.length - 1*.

Comment: Thank you. What I'm missing here is your logic. I thought that there had to be a iteration of the code and that was the purpose of my for loop. So you say I don't need it. Putting it in would be bloated code, is that what you're saying. Or would it not make the code work?

Answer (score 0):

a) are you just trying to show an animated gif? If so, why not use Adobe's Fireworks and merge all those gifs into a single gif?

b) you know that the way you have it the display is going to go crazy overwriting the gif in a circle right?


c) you might want to put a delay (or not). If so, make the load new gif a separate function and set a timeout to it (or an interval).
Also, you are being redundant. How about just changing the src for the image being displayed?:
var jackHammer = new Array();
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) { //pre-loading the images
    jackHammer[i] = new image();
    jackHammer[i].src = '/poses/jackHammer'+i.toString()+'.gif';
} //remember that "poses" without the "/" will only work if that folder is under the current called page.
for (var i=0;i<11;i++) { //updating the image on 
    document.getElementById('jhPoses').src = jackHammer[i].src;
}
on the document itself,
< img id='jhPoses' src='1-pixel-transparent.gif' width='x' height='y' alt='poses' border='0' />